# Is there anything wrong with FileWriter?

Tags: java, io

I don't know what's going on with the `FileWriter`, because it only writes out the HTML part, but nothing from the `String` array `content`. `content` stores a lot of long `String`s. Is it because of Java's garbage collector?

I print out the `content` and everything is there, but `FileWrter` did not write anything from `content` to that file except the HTML part. I added `System.out.println(k);` inside the enhanced for-loop. `content` array is not null though.

```
public void writeHtml(String[] content) {
    File file = new File("final.html");
    try {
        try (FileWriter Fw = new FileWriter(file)) {
            Fw.write("<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\">\n"
                    + "<html>\n"
                    + "<head>\n"
                    + "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=us-ascii\">\n"
                    + "<title>" + fileName +" for  The Delinquent</title>\n"
                    + "<style type = \"text/css\">\n"
                    + "body {font-family: \"Times New Roman, serif\"; font-size: 14 or 18; text-align: justify;};\n"
                    + "p { margin-left: 1%; margin-right: 1%; }\n"
                    + "</style>\n"
                    + "</head><body>");
            for (String k : content) {
                Fw.write(k+"\n");
            }
            Fw.write("</body></html>");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrack();
    }
}
```

How the final.html looks like after running the program:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=us-ascii">
<title>the_delinquent.txt for  The Delinquent</title>
<style type = "text/css">
body {font-family: "Times New Roman, serif"; font-size: 14 or 18; text-
align: justify;};
p { margin-left: 1%; margin-right: 1%; }
</style>
</head><body>
</body></html>
```

I know content is not empty because I did this:

```
 for (String k: content) {
                System.out.println(k + "\n");
                bw.write(k + "\n");
            }
```

Everything printed out. so weird : (

Comment: What do you mean by "except the HTML part" ? Can you show us how the current file content looks like?

Comment: for new line you need to use "\n".

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. You should always assume *your* code is at fault, not code that millions of developers around the world use. Yes, there's a chance that `FileWriter` has a bug in it, but it's far, far more likely that the problem is in your code. Without a [mcve] we won't be able to help you find the problem though.

Comment: *"Is there anything wrong with FileWriter?"* No. There might be with your use of it, but why assume it's the `FileWriter`, and not your own code?

Comment: The odds of something being intrinsically wrong with FileWriter vs with your assumptions on how it works are 1 to 100,000,000. Look at your own assumptions first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code iis basically correct, maybe the content array is empty.
The following is in modernized java style.

```
public void writeHtml(String[] content) {
    Path file = Paths.get("final.html");
    try (BufferedWriter fw = Files.newBufferedWriter(file, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
        fw.write("<!DOCTYPE html>\n"
                + "<html>\n"
                + "<head>\n"
                + "<meta charset=UTF-8\">\n"
                + "<title>" + fileName + " for  The Delinquent</title>\n"
                + "<style type = \"text/css\">\n"
                + "body {font-family: \"Times New Roman, serif\";"
                + " font-size: 14 or 18; text-align: justify;};\n"
                + "p { margin-left: 1%; margin-right: 1%; }\n"
                + "</style>\n"
                + "</head><body>");
        fw.write("Content has: " + content.length + " strings.<br>\n");
        for (String k : content) {
            fw.write("* " + k + "<br>\n");
        }
        fw.write("</body></html>\n");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

- FileWriter is an old utility class that uses the default charset, so not portable. Better specify the charset to correspond to the charset in HTML.
- The encoding UTF-8 allows full Unicode range of characters, like comma like quotes (typical to MS Word). Java internally also uses Unicode, so it is a fine match.
- HTML 5 is the latest HTML version, now generally disposable.
- At one spot a typo `/n` entered.
- Multiple spaces and line breaks are converted to a single space. So I added `<br>` for a line break.

Normally one would add to the method header `throws IOException` to let the caller handle any irregularities.

Comment: I updated the post, the content is not empty because I tried printing it out.

Comment: And the output was indeed pure ASCII, latin letters and such? Try my code too for comparison.

Answer (score 4):

You code is working. The only thing that prevents `content` to be written - empty `content`. It has no elements.

Comment: I updated the post, the content is not empty because I tried printing it out.